# iTextSharp System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, itext

I am getting a System.IO.FileNotFoundException on the release build of the below but not getting it while debugging.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
using iTextSharp.text.xml;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace CountingTool
{
    public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window
    {
        private string SelectedFile;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }        

        private void LoadFileButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog LoadFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            LoadFileDialog.Title = "Select file";
            LoadFileDialog.Filter = "PDF files|*.pdf";
            LoadFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";

            if (LoadFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    SelectedFile = LoadFileDialog.FileName;
                 }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        private void CountEach()
        {
            string FullPdf = ExtractFullPdf();
            ...
        }

        private string ExtractFullPdf()
        {
            PdfReader sourceDocument = new PdfReader(SelectedFile);
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 1; i <= sourceDocument.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                text.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(sourceDocument, i));
            }

            sourceDocument.Close();
            return text.ToString();
        }
}
```

The line that seems to be causing the issue is `PdfReader sourceDocument = new PdfReader(SelectedFile);`.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you running your executable within the same environment when you run the release vs test build?

Comment: @MattSpinks yep, I am. The build in /bin/Debug works fine, but the build in /bin/Debug/app.publish has issues.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that your try catch block is guarding something going wrong during a string to a string assignment.

Comment: Can you do a global search for "SelectedFile" in your project to verify that the only occurrences are in the three places that you listed above.

Comment: @RossBush I have it in two other place, in a check of ``if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedFile))`` and to set a textbox text ``FilenameTextBox.Text = SelectedFile;``

Comment: The code that you submitted looks ok besides changing your event handler from protected to private, I don't see anything that would cause the error. It is almost like you called your process file method prior to calling browse for file. Can you call your process file method multiple times while only selecting the file initially?

Comment: Also see if this line works --> new PdfReader(LoadFileDialog.FileName);. If it you do not get an error then there is an error somewhere else in your code.

Comment: One last one, are you using UNC file paths?

Comment: @RossBush neither of these helped unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was that the `itextsharp.dll` needs to be in the same directory as the built .exe.

Answer (score 0):

If you're completely sure that the path you've specified is correct even though that is probably unlikely then I can suggest you use either:

Request.PhysicalApplicationPath("enter path here");

Server.MapPath("enter path here");